# Remove a slice of seconds from every minute in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, time-series

I was wondering how it is possible to remove a slice of time from bigger time unit. Let us say we have a dataset from a day and we want to remove the first 10 seconds of every minute from this day. How can I do this in Pandas or Numpy?

The example shows values in a range of 15 min and the values between 06 am and 10 am are deleted. This should happen for everyday in the dataset. I hope you can help me.

```
Before:
2019-01-01 05:15:00    0.0
2019-01-01 05:30:00    0.0
2019-01-01 05:45:00    0.0
2019-01-01 06:00:00    0.0
2019-01-01 06:15:00    0.0

After:
2019-01-01 05:15:00    0.0
2019-01-01 05:30:00    0.0
2019-01-01 05:45:00    0.0
2019-01-01 10:15:00    0.0
2019-01-01 10:30:00    0.0
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

I tried this and it worked:

```
#The actual deleting of the rows between 6am and 10 am
def delete_row_by_time(df, day):
  from_ts = day + ' 06:00:00'
  to_ts = day +  ' 10:00:00'
  df = df[(df.index < from_ts) | (df.index > to_ts)]
  return df

#Get the actual days
days = eins.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').unique()
days = pd.to_datetime(days)

start_date = days.min()
end_date = days.max()
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

#iterate through all days in dataset
while start_date <= end_date:
  print(start_date)
  df = delete_row_by_time(df, str(start_date))
  start_date += delta
```

Maybe there are some improvements to make.

Comment: It's always good to show a `before` and an `after` so that the question is clear to all.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

The previous solutions were not going to work because you don't have a DateTime column but a DateTimeIndex so the syntax is a bit different.

Your solution works, however, this can be solved by using a pandas function that vectorizes so you don't have to go day by day in a `for/while` loop

```
from datetime import datetime

np.random.seed(0)
index = pd.date_range(datetime.now(), freq='15T', periods=1000)
sample_data = np.random.rand(1000)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(data=sample_data), index=index)

df = df[(df.index.hour < 6 ) | ((df.index.hour >= 10) & (df.index.minute > 0))]

df.iloc[20:26]

#       data
# 2020-04-22 05:00:00   0.978618
# 2020-04-22 05:15:00   0.799159
# 2020-04-22 05:30:00   0.461479
# 2020-04-22 05:45:00   0.780529
# 2020-04-22 10:15:00   0.437032
# 2020-04-22 10:30:00   0.697631
```

This solution will delete every hour between 6 AM and 10 AM including 10:00:00

Comment: Hi Jcaliz, sorry my intention was not clear. I edited my initial post maybe it is clear now which problem I have :)

Comment: Check the edit, it was done based on your description.

Comment: Make sure your column is a datetime object for example: `data['times'] = pd.to_datetime(data['times'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` you might have to adjust the `format` parameter, this is for the data, if you need a different format check https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: I added the proper solutions, be careful DateTime column syntax is slightly different than DateTimeIndex, that is why `dt` was not working.